# Optional indented newline in git log format

Tags: git, formatting, git-log

I have been tinkering with `git` aliases for some `log` commands. I have most of what I'd like ([credit here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/241211)), but I'm having trouble with one piece. When I call…

```bash
git log --graph --format=format:'%h - [%ar] %s%+d'
```

…I get…

```
* ab123f - [6 hours ago] Fix the references
|  (HEAD, origin/master, master)
* bc123f - [8 hours ago] New build syntax
* cd123f - [10 hours ago] Initial import
```

…where `%+d` adds a new line and puts the `--decorate` tags on it if they exist. I would rather have the tags to be in line with the *time stamp* instead, like so:

```
* ab123f - [6 hours ago] Fix the references
|          (HEAD, origin/master, master)
* bc123f - [8 hours ago] New build syntax
* cd123f - [10 hours ago] Initial import
```

How do I accomplish this? I do not want a bonus newline if there are no `--decorate` tags. I've been experimenting with various [format placeholders:](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) `%+d`, `%-d`, `%+    d` (which doesn't work); permutations of `%>(<N>)`, `%>>(<N>)`; and so on, but I can't get it to do what I want.

Colors and further commit info had been removed for simplicity, but they seem to interfere with [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416145/241211). The full command is below:

```bash
git log --graph --format=format:'%C(bold yellow)%h%C(reset) - %C(green)(%ar)%C(reset) %s %C(white)<%an>%C(reset)%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%w` as follows seems to do the trick.

```bash
git log --graph --format=format:'%h - [%ar] %-s%w(0,0,9)%+d'
```

Git version 1.8.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Ugh ... using `%n%-...` *almost* seems to work, but I still can't get it to do the right thing here.

Aha! `'%h - [%ar] %s%n%-w(80,9)%+d'` works!

This seems terribly clumsy (add a newline, maybe remove it, wrap lines with indent at 9, add a newline if %d is not empty), but the more obvious versions (with `%+w`, or `%w...%+d` without the `%n` and `%-` parts) don't work.

Comment: +1 I can confirm that this works for the test case provided. Unfortunately, it seems to choke on the full format with colors. I end up with a cute little `[m` at the end of the first line and no second line for reasons that are unclear to me. Do you know why that is?

Comment: No ... the %-language here is a nice idea, and simple things "just work", but beyond that, it sure gets messy.  I can't even explain why the part that works, works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `awk`—but the columns approach above is cleaner. This might take it all the way to what your looking for.

```bash
git log --format=format:'%h - [%ar%] %s %d' | awk -F'(' '{print $1} {if ( $2 != "" ) print "\t  ("$2}'
```

On the upside, this seems to preserve colors for me.

Answer (score 0):

For curious future visitors, these are what I eventually settled upon:

```ini
[alias]
    # Pretty logs
    lg1 = log --graph --date=auto:human --format=tformat:'%C(bold yellow)%h%C(reset) %C(green)%ad%C(reset) %s %C(dim white)%aN%C(reset) %w(0,0,9)%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)'
    lg2 = log --graph --format=tformat:'%C(bold yellow)%h%C(reset) %C(cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(green)(%ar) %C(dim white)%aN%C(reset)%w(0,0,9)%n %C(brightwhite)%s%C(auto)%+d%C(reset)%w(0,0,10)%+b'
    lg = lg1

    # Monochrome log
    lgs = log --graph --format=format:'%h - [%ar] %s%n%-w(80,9)%+d'
```

- `git lg` or `git lg1` for a `git log --oneline` analogue
- `git lg2` to include the body and full date (but also fuzzy date)
- `git lgs` as a simpler fallback in case the colors break

The colors do enough work to distinguish the parts that I no longer wrap most names and times. Also, `--date=auto:human` wasn't around for the original question, but I like it a lot.