# Git Commit message pretty format: Is there a way to format multi-line body

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to format my `git log` output with pretty formats. So far so good, but when using the 50/72 pattern, the wrapped body breaks the format (screenshot below for reference).

Is there a way to keep the format of the first body line on the subsequent lines?

[image: demo]

Pretty format I am using:

```bash
git log --graph --format=format:" | %C(bold yellow)%D%Creset%n | %Cred%h%Creset | %C(cyan)%an%Creset | %Cgreen%cr%Creset%n | %s%n | %C(dim normal)%b%n"
```

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22415347/241211), though without the leading pipe characters.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a body format using `%w(maxWidth, firstLineIndent, secondLineIndent)`:

```bash
git log --graph \
 --format=format:" \
| %C(bold yellow)%D%Creset%n \
| %Cred%h%Creset | %C(cyan)%an%Creset | %Cgreen%cr%Creset%n \
| %s%n \
| %C(dim normal)%w(,,3)%b%n"
```

I recommend using simple, normal white for the body color and bold white for `%s`.

Here's mine, using

```bash
git log --graph \
 --pretty=format:"%n \
%C(bold blue)[state] %C(bold yellow)%D%Creset%n \
%C(bold blue)[info.] %Cred%h%Creset | %C(cyan)%an%Creset | %Cgreen%cr%Creset%n \
%C(bold blue)[title] %C(bold white)%s%Creset%n \
%C(bold blue)%n %w(,10,11)%b"
```

[image: Screenshot showing the format above in use]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the `%<|(<N>)`, `%>|(<N>)` and `%>>|(<N>)` [placeholders](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) to force the correct alignment directly through *git log formatting*, but it just does not wanna work with the `--graph` option.

I ended up using `%x00` [placeholder](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) to insert `0x01` as a separator between my fields and passing the output of *git log* through [column](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) to do proper alignment based on that separator.

I put the final result in a [git plugin](https://github.com/hdoradu/config/blob/master/git/git-lg) which prints one line per commit, but the same thing can be applied to your custom formatting like so:

```sh
git log --graph \
  --pretty="%x01%n \ 
  | %C(bold yellow)%D%Creset%n \
  | %Cred%h%Creset | %C(cyan)%an%Creset | %Cgreen%cr%Creset%n \
  | %s%n \
  | %C(dim normal)%b%n%x01" \
| column -s $'\001' -t
```

---

Regardless of this, you would be much better off just using something like [tig](https://github.com/jonas/tig) for navigating your repository.